# How to move the multiple JSlider according to their assigned JTextField

Tags: java, jslider

I need to move the slider with the values in accordance with the respective textfield in JSwing. I got to move the first JSlider accordingly, but when entering values in second JSlider invoking First to move also with second JSlider. Just want to move the respective slider when the assigned textField is entered with values

Here's code for you :

```
package sliderexample;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel; 
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;


public class BlueSliderBeanFrame extends JFrame implements DocumentListener       {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
/**
 * 
 */
private JPanel contentPane;
private JTextField textField;


JSlider slider = new JSlider();
private JTextField textField_1;
JSlider slider_2 = new JSlider();


/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                BlueSliderBeanFrame frame = new BlueSliderBeanFrame();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public BlueSliderBeanFrame() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.getDocument().putProperty("owner", textField);
    textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(this);
    textField.setBounds(53, 37, 125, 50);
    contentPane.add(textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);

    textField_1 = new JTextField();
    textField_1.getDocument().putProperty("owner", textField_1);
    textField_1.getDocument().addDocumentListener(this);
    textField_1.setColumns(10);
    textField_1.setBounds(53, 126, 125, 50);
    contentPane.add(textField_1);


    slider.setValue(0);
    slider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent arg0) {
                textField.setText(String.valueOf(slider.getValue()));
                }
        });
    slider.setMaximum(999);
    slider.setBounds(188, 37, 200, 50);
    contentPane.add(slider);

    slider_2.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        textField.setText(String.valueOf(slider_2.getValue()));
        }
    });
    slider_2.setValue(0);
    slider_2.setMaximum(999);
    slider_2.setBounds(188, 126, 200, 50);
    contentPane.add(slider_2);




}



public void updateSlider( int i ) {

    Runnable doHighlight = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
     // your highlight code
     int val = 0;
     System.out.println(" i val : "+i);
     if( i == 1 ){
            val = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());
            System.out.println("owner1 slider");
            slider.setValue(val);
     } else if ( i == 2 ){
            val = Integer.parseInt(textField_1.getText());
            System.out.println("owner2 slider");
            slider_2.setValue(val);
     }
 }};   

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(doHighlight);

}

@Override
public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    /*Object owner = arg0.getDocument().getProperty("owner");
    if( owner == textField ){
            System.out.println("owner1");
            updateSlider(1);
    } else if ( owner == textField_1 ){
        System.out.println("owner2");
            updateSlider(2);
    }*/
       if (arg0.getDocument()== textField.getDocument()){
            System.out.println("event caused by field");
            updateSlider(1);
        }
        else if (arg0.getDocument()== textField_1.getDocument()){
            System.out.println("event caused by field2");
            updateSlider(2);
        }
}

@Override
public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

Output :

[image]

Kindly anyone help me with this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need to update your code little bit,

Updated Code :

```
 slider_2.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
         /* 
         here you did wrong...
         textField.setText(String.valueOf(slider_2.getValue()));
         */
        textField_1.setText(String.valueOf(slider_2.getValue()));
        }
    });
```

See Out-put :

[image]